# Is it possible to hide an enum value from a PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, enums, propertygrid

I'm working with the `PropertyGrid` control and using the `SelectedObject` property to display data within the `PropertyGrid`. Some of the properties in my grid are enum types. What I'd like to be able to do is hide some of the selections within the enum from the user. Take the below example: I would like to hide the enum of "Error" from the user. Is there a way to do this?

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(PropertySorter))]
public class Settings
{
    public enum FooType { Type1, Type2, Type3, Type4, Error };
    private FooType fakeProperty = FooType.Type1;

    public FooType FakeProperty
    {
        get { return fakeProperty; }
        set { // Do Something }
    }
}
```

And I am displaying the data in the `PropertyGrid` by calling:

```
myPropertyGrid.SelectedObject = mySettings;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Visibility in `PropertyGrid` is usually controlled by `[Browsable(...)]`. So you could add `[Browsable(false)]` to your `Error` option. For example:

```
public enum Foo {
    A,
    [Browsable(false)] B
    C
}
```

[image]

Comment: This was so much more simple than I thought it would be. Thanks Marc!