# Is there a way for hiding some enum values for specific property of class?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer, propertygrid

I have **enum** lets say for example:

```
public enum Color
{
  red,
  green,
  blue
}
```

And have two classes. which have property of **enum**.

```
public class ClassA
{
    public Color Color{get;set;}
}

public class ClassB
{
    [InvisibleFlag(Color.red)]  // I want something like that
    public Color Color{get;set;}
}
```

Now in Windows Forms Designer, I want to hide the red flag only from the Color enumeration for ClassB only.

I know that I can create a separated enum. but why duplicate values? I gave a simple example only.

> Something I guess might help for superior who can help me at it.
>
> Descriptor API. which I hate. ;(

Maybe something like `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(object, new BrowsableAttribute(false));`

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652461/is-it-possible-to-hide-an-enum-value-from-a-propertygrid) will not work in this case. I don't want to apply `Browsable` attribute to the enum flags because it hides that flag in property grid for all classes. I want to be able to hide specific enum values for specific classes only, not for all classes.

Comment: You can use a TypeConverter, where, in the `GetStandardValues()` method override, you can filter the Enum values to return a new collection that excludes the Value specified by the `InvisibleFlag` attribute. You also have to override `CanConvertFrom` and `ConvertFrom`, to convert the string representation of the Enum to an Enum value. You also need to create the `InvisibleFlag` custom attribute, with two constructors: one that accepts the enum type and one that accepts a string. A `[DefaultValue(...)]` attribute should be used, to avoid a default assignment to an excluded enum value.

Comment: @Ňɏssa: _"This has nothing at all to do with Windows forms designer"_ -- doesn't it? it seems like they are asking _specifically_ to adjust the behavior in the Designer. I.e. to prevent the `red` value from being an option in the property grid for the class when shown in the Designer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The class which helps you to show the enum values in `PropertyGrid` is [`EnumConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.enumconverter?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) and the method which is responsible to list enum values in [`GetStandardValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.enumconverter.getstandardvalues?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8).

So as an option, you can can create a custom enum converter class by deriving from `EnumConverter` and the override its `GetStandardValues` to return standard values based on a specific attribute which you have for the property.

**How to get context information like attributes of property in `TypeConverter` methods?**

An instance of [`ITypeDescriptorContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.itypedescriptorcontext?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) class is passed to `context` parameter of the `TypeConverter` method. Using that class, you have access to the object which is being edited and the property descriptor of the property which is being edited  has some useful properties. Here you can rely on
[`PropertyDescriptor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.itypedescriptorcontext.propertydescriptor?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property of the context and get the `Attributes` and check if the specific attribute in which we are interested, has been set for the property.

**Example**

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExcludeColorTypeConverter))]
public enum Color
{
    Red,
    Green,
    Blue,
    White,
    Black,
}
public class ExcludeColorAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Color[] Exclude { get; private set; }
    public ExcludeColorAttribute(params Color[] exclude)
    {
        Exclude = exclude;
    }
}
public class ExcludeColorTypeConverter : EnumConverter
{
    public ExcludeColorTypeConverter() : base(typeof(Color))
    {
    }
    public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(
        ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        var original = base.GetStandardValues(context);
        var exclude = context.PropertyDescriptor.Attributes
            .OfType<ExcludeColorAttribute>().FirstOrDefault()?.Exclude
            ?? new Color[0];
        var excluded = new StandardValuesCollection(
            original.Cast<Color>().Except(exclude).ToList());
        Values = excluded;
        return excluded;
    }
}
```

As an example of the usage:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    [ExcludeColor(Color.White, Color.Black)]
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Reza i really want to say that a real man is real man, you do harder things for us easy for you. Thanks you a real man.

Comment: Reza, sorry but I omit the   Values = excluded, and code still works ? is this property important?

Comment: `Color` property of `ClassA` is an example of a property which doesn't have `ExcludeColor` and it still works. In fact by decorating the enum using `[TypeConverter(typeof(ExcludeColorTypeConverter))]` we are telling all properties of this enum type should use this type converter. Then in `GetStandardValues` method of `ExcludeColorTypeConverter` we check if the property has any `ExcludeColor` attribute, then we exclude those values from list, otherwise we show original list values (all enums).